# Use of XSD Duration type, using XSLT to out put value to normal duration format

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I am storing a duration in my XML, in my Schema I have set this as a duration type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" 
attributeFormDefault="unqualified">


<xs:element name="flights">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="flight" type="flighttype" minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded'>
      <xs:unique name="planeidisunique">
        <xs:selector xpath="plane"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@planeid"/>
      </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:unique name="flightidisunique">
  <xs:selector xpath="flight"/>
  <xs:field xpath="@flightid"/>
</xs:unique>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="flighttype">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="flightno" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="callsign" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="airline" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="plane" type="planetype" minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
    <xs:element name="route" type="routetype"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="flightid" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- PLANE -->

<xs:complexType name="planetype" mixed="true">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="speed" type="speedtype"/>
    <xs:element name="wingspan" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="length" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="registereddate" type="xs:date"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="planeid" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>


<!-- ALTITUDE -->

<xs:complexType name="altitudetype">
<xs:simpleContent>
  <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
    <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:string">
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>


<!-- SPEED THE VALUE OF SPEED MUST BE AN INTEGER-->

<xs:complexType name="speedtype">
<xs:simpleContent>
  <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
    <xs:attribute name="ratio" type="xs:string">
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>



  <!-- DISTANCE VALUE OF DISTANCE MUST BE AN INTEGER-->

<xs:complexType name="distancetype">
<xs:simpleContent>
  <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
    <xs:attribute name="unit" type="xs:string">
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>


<!-- COURSE -->

<xs:complexType name="coursetype">
<xs:simpleContent>
  <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
    <xs:attribute name="bearing" type="xs:string">
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>



  <!-- DURATION -->

<xs:complexType name="durationtype">
<xs:simpleContent>
  <xs:extension base="xs:duration">
  </xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>



<!-- ROUTE -->


<xs:complexType name="routetype">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="routename" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="altitude" type="altitudetype" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="speed" type="speedtype" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="course" type="coursetype"/>
    <xs:element name="distance" type="distancetype"/>
    <xs:element name="duration" type="durationtype"/>
    <xs:element name="from" type="fromtype"/>
    <xs:element name="to" type="totype"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>



<!-- FROM -->

<xs:complexType name="fromtype">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="iatacode"/>
    <xs:element name="airport"/>
    <xs:element name="country"/>
    <xs:element name="city"/>
    <xs:element name="latitude"/>
    <xs:element name="longitude"/>
    <xs:element name="yahoowoeid"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- TO -->

<xs:complexType name="totype">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="iatacode"/>
    <xs:element name="airport"/>
    <xs:element name="country"/>
    <xs:element name="city"/>
    <xs:element name="latitude"/>
    <xs:element name="longitude"/>
    <xs:element name="yahoowoeid"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>


</xs:schema>
```

In my XML I use duration like this:

```
<duration>PT12H37M</duration>
```

Here is my XSL file, I have put a comment in where I use the duration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:output doctype-public="-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" doctype-system="http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd"/>

<!-- Parameters for the map longitudes and latitudes and route name-->
<xsl:param name="a" />
<xsl:param name="b" />
<xsl:param name="c" />
<xsl:param name="d" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="html">
        <xsl:element name="head">
            <xsl:element name="title">Selected Flight Route</xsl:element>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css" title="Style"/>
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="body"> 

            <xsl:element name="div"><!-- This holds the navigation bar-->
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:text>navdiv</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>


                <xsl:element name="div"><!-- This holds the image links-->
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:text>navlinks</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:element name="a">
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">
                            <xsl:text>navlinksone</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">flights.php</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>

                    <xsl:element name="a">
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">
                            <xsl:text>navlinkstwo</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">planes.php</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>

                    <xsl:element name="a">
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">
                            <xsl:text>navlinksthree</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">weatherfeed.php</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>

                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element><!-- End the navigation bar-->

            <xsl:element name="div">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">mapdiv</xsl:attribute>
                <img width="300" height="270" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=300x270&amp;zoom=1&amp;path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:4|{$a},{$b}|{$c},{$d}
                    &amp;markers=color%3ablue|label%3aA|
                    {$a},{$b}|&amp;markers=color%3agreen|label%3aB|{$c},{$d}
                    &amp;sensor=false" />
            </xsl:element>

            <xsl:element name="hr"></xsl:element>


            <!-- The following is the table which holds all of the map and route information -->
            <table><xsl:attribute name="class">tab</xsl:attribute>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><xsl:attribute name="class">top</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/routename"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute></td>
                    <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>From<img src="bm.png" height="18" width="12"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>To<img src="gm.png" height="18" width="12"/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>City</td>
                    <td><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/from/city"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/to/city"/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>IATA Code</td>
                    <td><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/from/iatacode"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/to/iatacode"/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr >
                    <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>Country</td>
                   <td><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/from/country"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/to/country"/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>Weather</td>


                        <td><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:element name="a">
                                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                                    <xsl:text>weatherimagelinks</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">weather.php?woeid=<xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/from/yahoowoeid" /></xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </td>
                          <td><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:element name="a">
                                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                                    <xsl:text>weatherimagelinks</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">weather.php?woeid=<xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/to/yahoowoeid" /></xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>Distance</td>
                        <td colspan="2"><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/distance"/><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/distance/@unit"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>Course</td>
                        <td colspan="2"><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/course"/><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/course/@bearing"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>Airline</td>
                        <td colspan="2"><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/../airline"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>Flight No</td>
                        <td colspan="2"><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/../flightno"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>Call Sign</td>
                        <td colspan="2"><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/../callsign"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
<!-- THIS IS WHERE I OUTPUT THE DURATION AND I THINK THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO TRANSFORM IT -->
                        <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>Duration</td>
                        <td colspan="2"><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/duration"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>Altitude</td>
                        <td colspan="2"><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/altitude"/><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/altitude/@height"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>Speed</td>
                        <td colspan="2"><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/speed"/><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/speed/@ratio"/></td>
                    </tr>




               <tr>
                    <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>Aircraft</td>
                     <td colspan="3">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>
                            <a><xsl:attribute name="href">aircraft.php?a=<xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/plane[../route/routename/. =$code]/name" /></xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/plane[../route/routename/. =$code]/name"/>
                            </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>    
            <!-- End the map and route table -->

        </xsl:element>
        <!-- End the Body element -->

    </xsl:element>
    <!-- End the Html element -->

</xsl:template>
<!-- End the Main Template element -->
```

How can I transform the duration so it is normal on the screen, from PT12H37M to 12 h 37 m?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime?

In that case you can use

```
<xsl:template match="duration">
  <xsl:variable name="d" select="xs:dayTimeDuration(.)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(days-from-duration($d), ' h ', minutes-from-duration($d), ' m')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-minutes-from-duration.

If you want to stick with your single template stylesheet then replace

```
                    <tr>
<!-- THIS IS WHERE I OUTPUT THE DURATION AND I THINK THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO TRANSFORM IT -->
                        <td><xsl:attribute name="class">lside</xsl:attribute>Duration</td>
                        <td colspan="2"><xsl:attribute name="class">rside</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/duration"/></td>
                    </tr>
```

with

```
                    <tr>
<!-- THIS IS WHERE I OUTPUT THE DURATION AND I THINK THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO TRANSFORM IT -->
                        <td class="lside">Duration</td>
                        <xsl:variable name="d" select="xs:dayTimeDuration(/flights/flight/route[routename/. = $code]/duration)" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
                        <td colspan="2" class="rside"><xsl:value-of select="concat(days-from-duration($d), ' h ', minutes-from-duration($d), ' m')"/></td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, could you show me where I would put that code in my XSL file? Also can I just change the version from 1.0 to 2.0 at the top of my XSL document?

Comment: No, changing the version to 2.0 does not enable XSLT 2.0 support. To use XSLT 2.0 you need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime. I will edit my answer to try to show code that integrates into your existing approach although using single template XSLT is not a good approach to processing XML in my view.

Comment: Thank you Martin, I do not know how to use an XSLT 2.0 Processor, I am going to look this up and try your code. Many thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your XSLT is incredibly verbose. Did you know? that instead of writing this:

```
            <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:text>navlinkstwo</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">planes.php</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
```

you can write this:

```
<a id="navlinkstwo" href="planes.php"/>
```

Secondly, you haven't said how it is failing. Martin has guessed that perhaps you are not using an XSLT 2.0 processor, but that seems to be pure guesswork based on no evidence. If you told us how it failed, we wouldn't have to guess.

Comment: I only started using XSL a week ago, I am learning more and more everyday, thanks for the tip on how to clean up my code. I am not aware of XSLT processors, all I have ever done is create this XSLT document and moved it to my server, so forgive me for not knowing anything about this enough to have included it in my question. I am about to research this now.

Comment: Michael Kay, I have been thinking a lot about your statement on how my code is Verbose. Can I ask, Isn't my code XSLT Strict? What is the main difference between the way I have it and your suggested way of doing it, I keep thinking about this. Thank you.

Comment: The main difference is that your code (in the sample shown) is 6 lines and mine is 1, and they do the same thing. 6 lines takes longer to write and takes longer to read, it means there's more scope for bugs and it's harder to spot them.