# Time duration calculation

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following time duration

```
<EstimatedTime>
  <Value>PT0H3M05S</Value>
</EstimatedTime>
```

The expected output is

> 03.05

Any ideas, please.

Comment: You need to parse the string using the xslt string functions... http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/xpathFunctionIndex.html

Comment: Found the solution via the search: [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955794/use-of-xsd-duration-type-using-xslt-to-out-put-value-to-normal-duartion-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your processor supports **XSLT 2.0**, you can use:

```
<xsl:template match="EstimatedTime">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(minutes-from-duration(Value), '00')"/>
    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(seconds-from-duration(Value), '00')"/>
</xsl:template>
```